# Как передать знаение в поле input

Tags: html, формы, php

Здравствуй ХешКод. Уже бьюсь около недели, никак не могу передать значение <input'y>. Есть форма от ИнтерКассы:

```
<form name="payment" action="https://www.interkassa.com/lib/payment.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="cp1251"> 
<tr><td style = "text-align: right;">Адрес баннера: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "image" value = ""></td></tr>
<tr><td style = "text-align: right;">Адрес сайта: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "url" value = ""></td></tr>
<tr><td style = "text-align: right;">Количество дней: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "plan" OnChange = "getZakaz(this.form)" value = "0"></td></tr>
<tr><td style = "text-align: right;">Текст при наведении: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "text" value = ""></td></tr>
<tr>
<td style = "text-align: right;">Стоимость заказа: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="ik_payment_amount" value="0.00" readonly></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<input type="hidden" name="ik_shop_id" value="ID_SHOP"> 
<input type="hidden" name="ik_payment_id" value="PAYMENT_ID"> 
<input type="text" name="ik_payment_desc" value="Действие Баннер100х100 Дней <?=$_POST["plan"];?> URL <?=$_POST["url"];?> image <?=$_POST["image"]?> text <?=$_POST["text"]?>"> 
<center><input type="submit" name="process" value="Оплатить"></center>
</form>
```

Так-вот мне нужно передать значения из полей в поле ik_payment_desc, я попытался сделать так <?=$_POST["имя поля"]?>, но они почему-то ничего не передают. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно нужно передать...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно надо не

```
<?=$_POST["имя поля"]?>
```

,а

```
<? echo $_POST["имя поля"]; ?>
```

Это во первых!
А во вторых позже советую почитать о проверке переменных перед тем как куда-нибудь вставлять. Иначе кроме url,image и text еще что-нибудь вставят.

Answer (score 0):

сделал бы шаблон, в нем атрибуты и при рендеренги заменил их на php значениями. Да и проверку за 1 там же реализовать.

Comment: Я думаю что судя  по такому еще простому вопросу это у него   в будующем.
А вот проверочку надобно в первую очередь! А то кто-то будет бесплатно заказывать баннера :)))

Comment: Мне кажется сразу надо писать нормально, а то приходится править такой код (временами) который проще заного написать. Да и MVC как то изучать надо до того как начинаешь че то писать. Тут че то в форме если править надо будет голову сломает тот же верстальщик... IMHO